# Mitigaing OS Injection attack vulnerability on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I work on an app that is scanned by the Burp tool before the code is released to production. The recent scan has resulted in OS Injection attack vulnerabilities.

In doing research the only examples of OS injection attacks I saw were for unix, java, php apps.

Are these attacks possible against an ASP.NET (MVC) application?  If so, how do you mitigate this risk? Does ASP.NET (and/or MVC) itself prevent OS Injection attacks?

Answer (score 3):

The framework is not vulnerable to OS injection attacks itself. It is the code that you write with this framework that can be vulnerable. For example if you have a controller action that executes a command that is passed as parameter from the outside your application immediately becomes vulnerable. Consider this example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string fileName, string arguments)
{
    Process.Start(fileName, arguments).WaitForExit();
    return View();
}
```

So basically no matter what framework or programming language you are using for developing your application you should never trust user input and perform proper sanitation before accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

OS Injection is [defined by the OWASP Foundation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OS_Injection) as follows:

> Operating system commands Calling external applications from your application.
>
> [...]
>
> What we should be looking for are relationships between the application and the operating system. The application utilising functions of the underlying operating system.
>
> In java using the Runtime object, java.lang.Runtime does this. In .NET calls such as System.Diagnostics.Process.Start are used to call underlying OS functions. In PHP we may look for calls such as exec() or passthru().

But of course your research already showed that.

> Are these attacks possible against an ASP.NET/MVC application?

So, yes, anywhere you use, or any library you use uses `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`, either directly or indirectly supplied with user input, you're at risk.

> If so, how do you mitigate this risk?

As usual, by properly escaping and sanitizing user input where necessary. This includes not only query string or route parameters, but also cookies, HTTP headers and whatnot.